# How do I add an item after databinding?

Tags: c#, windows, xaml

I'm attempting to bind some data to a gridview, then have a button at the end (similar to the MSN Finance app on Windows 8).

How would I achieve this?

My current xaml code:

```
            <DataTemplate>
                <GridView
                    x:Name="StopGridViewItem"
                    ItemsSource="{Binding}"
                    Margin="0,0,20,20"
                    AutomationProperties.AutomationId="ItemGridView"
                    AutomationProperties.Name="Items In Group"
                    ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard310x260ItemTemplate}"
                    SelectionMode="None"
                    IsSwipeEnabled="false"
                    IsItemClickEnabled="True" ItemClick="StopGridViewItem_ItemClick">
                </GridView>


            </DataTemplate>
```

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many, many ways to handle this scenario.

If you are dealing with a simple list and not a dynamic mosaic like the one we see on the right of your screenshot, you can simply place a button just after your list, styled so that it looks like one of the items of your list. This works really well when you are dealing with a list that does not scroll automatically and is the most semantic solution.

```
<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl
            x:Name="StopGridViewItem"
            ItemsSource="{Binding}"
            ItemTemplate="{StaticResource Standard310x260ItemTemplate}">
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button ... />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

If you need to support scrolling, or are dealing with a control that cannot simply push your button further down like a mosaic, you need to add a dummy item inside the collection that you bind to your list. If list virtualization is not an issue, you could simply append it at the end of your collection inside a converter. If you need to support virtualization, then this is not a solution. You will need a custom control to handle this case.

Finally, once the dummy item is inserted in the list, you can use a DataTemplateSelector to switch between your normal template and your dummy template when generating the item in the view.

```
public static class EnumerableExtensions
{
    public static IEnumerable Append(this IEnumerable source, object o)
    {
        foreach (var x in source)
        {
            yield return x;
        }

        yield return o;
    }
}

public class DummyInserter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var source = value as IEnumerable;
        if (source == null)    throw new UnsupportedException("DummyInserter converter requires an IEnumerable source");

        return source.Append(new Dummy()).ToArray();
    }
}
```

And for the XAML:

```
<Resources>
    <DummyInserter x:key="AddButtonDummyInserter" />
    <DummyTemplateSelector x:key="MySelector"
                           DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource Standard310x260ItemTemplate}"
                           DummyTemplate="{StaticResource 310x260AddButtonTemplate}" />
</Resources>

<DataTemplate>
    <StackPanel>
        <ItemsControl
            x:Name="StopGridViewItem"
            ItemsSource="{Binding, Converter={StaticResource AddButtonDummyInserter}}"
            ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MySelector}">
        </ItemsControl>

        <Button ... />
    </StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1):

Add it to the `ObservableCollection<T>` of whatever that `GridView`'s `ItemsSource` is binded to.

---

If the `Footer` and `GridRow` wasn't enough.  Then you can do it the more complicated way by using a `ItemTemplateSelector`

```
<Page.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AddTemplate">
        <Button Command="{Binding}" Content="{Binding Title}" Height="100" MinHeight="100" Width="100" MinWidth="100"/>
    </DataTemplate>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="DefaultTemplate">
        <Border BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red">
            <StackPanel Height="100" MinHeight="100" Width="100" MinWidth="100">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Artist}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Song}"></TextBlock>
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </DataTemplate>
    <local:MyTemplateSelector x:Key="MyTemplateSelector" AddTemplate="{StaticResource AddTemplate}" DefaultTemplate="{StaticResource DefaultTemplate}"></local:MyTemplateSelector>
</Page.Resources>

<GridView x:Name="myGV" ItemTemplateSelector="{StaticResource MyTemplateSelector}"></GridView>
```

---

```C#
public class MyTemplateSelector : DataTemplateSelector
{
    public DataTemplate AddTemplate { get; set; }

    public DataTemplate DefaultTemplate { get; set; }


    protected override Windows.UI.Xaml.DataTemplate SelectTemplateCore(object item, Windows.UI.Xaml.DependencyObject container)
    {
        if (item is sample_model)
        {
            return DefaultTemplate;
        }
        else
        {
            return AddTemplate;
        }
    }
}
```

---

Basically you can add as many `models` as you want into the `GridView.Items`,  all it does is it check what model type it is, if it is the sample_model (your model) it will use the default template, but if it is not the default model then it uses the AddTemplate (which is the button one)

Example output using sample_model of (Artrist/Song) and a non default model with just a `Title` Property

[image]

Comment: But what about if the item is not the same as the other objects? E.g. A "+" button instead of the standard data set

Comment: @ForeverLearning that "+" button is not part of the ItemTemplate, it's part of the `<GridView.FooterTemplate></GridView.FooterTemplate>`  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.templatefield.footertemplate(v=vs.110).aspx  (so basically it's an item you can always have at the end of the list, with its own binding/template)

Comment: @ForeverLearning you can also add the "+" as a separate row if you include the list in the row above in the top container.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, tried this, but the footertemplate creates a seperate column within the gridview containing the button rather than tagging it on to the end of the list of items?

Comment: @Chubosaurus Software This will not keep the button within the list. The footer is drawn independently of the list which will cause issues if your panel is not a simple, unidirectional panel like a stackpanel.

Comment: @ForeverLearning then you probably need to do it a more complicated way to achieved it fully.  I updated the solution.