# Windows Phone 8.1 conditional formatting

Tags: xaml, formatting, windows-phone-8.1, conditional-statements

I would like to display some data on a ListView. The data is getting from a HttpClient request, but it's not so important at the moment. In the ListView I use Stackpanel and in this there are the datas. I would like to format the Stackpanel and the Textblocks inside the Stackpanel depending to their values. I can do it, but only in a complex way.
Here is my C# code:

```
public class TransTypeToAlignConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        var ttype = (int)value;
        HorizontalAlignment align;

        switch (ttype)
        {
            case 1:
            case 3:
                align = HorizontalAlignment.Right;
                break;
            case 2:
                align = HorizontalAlignment.Left;
                break;
            case 6:
                align = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                break;
            default:
                align = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch;
                break;
        }
        return align;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And the XAML code:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <local:TransTypeToAlignConverter x:Key="TransTypeToAlign" />
</Page.Resources>

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <ListView x:Name="myList" Height="Auto" Grid.Row="1">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch" />
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid Margin="10,0,10,0">
                    <Rectangle Fill="DarkGray" Width="320" Margin="3,18,0,0" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding transactionType, Converter={StaticResource TransTypeToAlign}}"/>
                    <StackPanel Width="320" Margin="0,13,3,3" HorizontalAlignment="{Binding transactionType, Converter={StaticResource TransTypeToAlign}}" Background="Gray">
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

As I mentioned, this code is working. But I would like to format other things as well, not the Alignment only. For example I would like a dynamic Stackpanel width, not the fix 320px. For this I should write a code similar to the above. I think it's too much code for a similar thing, and it will be hard to modify later.

I have one value (TransType) which defines the alignment, the stackpanel width, the textblock message, and the color of the text. So, is it possible to make a template for formatting xaml?

Comment: How about writing your own element that inherits a stackpanel?

Comment: I pasted more code. Please check. The Stackpanel contains more elements in a Grid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A criticism of the pattern comes from MVVM creator John Gossman himself, who points out that the overhead in implementing MVVM is "overkill" for simple UI operations. [MVVM Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_ViewModel)

You can either do it with multiple converters or you can do it with a `ItemTemplateSelector`, in the latter case you would need to defined each template separately.

SO example of using `ItemTemplateSelector`

[GridView ItemTemplateSelector](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26918302/how-do-i-add-an-item-after-databinding/26918951#26918951)

Comment: Thanks, it was very helpful! And my app's working perfectly with this (at least this function) :)